# What is ** in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've seen some code, as well as some errors generated from my compiler that have a '`**`' token before the variable (eg **variablename unreferenced-- or something, I can't recall exactly offhand).  I'm fairly certain this is related to pointers, if I had to guess it looks like it's trying to dereference twice.  '`**`' is fairly ungoogleable.  Can someone point me to a good website/documentation or would someone care to explain it here?

Thanks.

Great responses.  If I can add, what would be some situations where it is useful to have a pointer to a pointer?  Shouldn't you just be using the original pointer instead of creating yet another pointer to the original pointer?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`**` is not actually only pointer to pointer (as in declaration), but is also the dereference of a dereference (in a statement).

It is used often in C which does not have the & notation for references, e.g. to update a return value which is a pointer type:

```
int alloc_foo(struct foo **foo_ret)
{
    *foo_ret = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    return 1; /* to indicate success; return value in foo_ret */
}
```

Answer (score 50):

You may recognize the signature for main():

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

The following is equivalent:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

In this case, argv is a pointer to an array of char*.

In C, the index operator [] is just another way of performing pointer arithmetic.  For example,

```
foo[i]
```

produces the same code as

```
*(foo + i)
```

Answer (score 14):

It's not a `**` token. It's simply a `*` token followed by another `*` token. In your case, you have a pointer to a  pointer, and it's being dereferenced twice to get whatever's really being pointed to.

Answer (score 11):

`**` is a pointer to a pointer.

It might be a matrix (an array of arrays) or an array of strings (a `char` array), etc.

Answer (score 7):

It's a double dereference.

```
int i = 3;
int* ptr_to_i = &i;
int** ptr_to_ptr_to_i = &ptr_to_i;

std::cout << **ptr_to_ptr_to_i << std::endl;
```

Prints 3.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to underscore some of the uses for a pointer to a pointer.  Most of these **are** touched on by other posts, but I thought reiteration might help.

- It allows a callee to *modify* a pointer owned by the caller.  For example, one could pass a pointer to a pointer to the beginning of a string, and the callee could modify the pointed-to pointer to now point to a position within the string where a particular character occurs.
- Because arrays degrade to pointers (and pointers can be treated as arrays), you will often see a pointer to a pointer if you have:

  - A pointer to an array.  This is a generalization of the above case, since a "string" (a C-style string, anyway) is really just an array of `char`s.
  - An array of pointers.  You might, for example, have an array of pointers to objects, allowing for polymorphism, or an array of pointers to select objects stored in another collection.
  - An array of arrays.  Again, arrays degrade to pointers, so this is a specific case of the above.  This is often used for so called "jagged" arrays (as opposed to rectangular).

Answer (score 5):

You can interpret it literally -- [pointer to a pointer](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node12.html)

Answer (score 3):

- `int **var` declares a pointer to a pointer
- `**var` references the content of a pointer, which in itself points to a pointer

Answer (score 1):

One common use is that it allows a function to set the pointer to null.
So free(pointer) frees up the memory allocated to pointer but leaves the pointer dangerously pointing at the free memory.
Instead declare a my_free(**pointer) and call my_free(&pointer) so my_free() can set the pointer to null after freeing it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the allures of C++ Sigils. From my own personal experience, I can vouch faster and more efficient read-access performance using dereference operators on STL's Arrays & Vectors. I've also adopted habitual shared pointer methods if you're curious. :)