# Unable to make Firefox open Ack's output

Tags: macos, firefox, ack

I aim to have a list of lines where I use the word NB in my notes.

**Pseudo-code**

```
open -a Firefox `ack -a NB`
```

However, I cannot make Firefox to understand parameters from terminal.
The output of Ack is a text-file, so it should be somehow redirected to Firefox.

I run unsuccessfully

```
open "http://`ack -a NB`"
```

I get in Firefox's address bar

```
http://[1/;32mACK-grep/.todo%1B%5B0m:3:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20to%20find%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0ms%20use%20ack%20-a%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mAPI/.todo%1B%5B0m:5:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mAWK/.todo%1B%5B0m:5:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Changing%20the%20field%20separator.%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20do%20non%20confuse%20the%20field%20separator%20to%20small%20f%20i.e.%20-f%20for%20the%20name%20of%20a%20script%20file%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mBg-disown/.todo%1B%5B0m:12:%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20disowning%20is%20a%20one%20way%20street.%20There%20is%20no%20way%20to%20reattach%20as%20with%20screen.%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mC-C++/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:6:%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20endl%20indicates%20line%20output.%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mC-C++/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:38:%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20stdexcept%20allows%20standard%20exceptions%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mC-C++/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:45:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20ensure%20that%20the%20user%27s%20given%20value%20is%20not%20eg%20string%20when%20the%20program%20wants%20a%20figure%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mC-C++/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:63:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20&amp;num%20is%20same%20as%20num&amp;%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mC-C++/Special-facts/.todo%1B%5B0m:3:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20**in%20C++:%20http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644981/what-is-in-c/644989%23644989%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mCompilers/3goals/.todo%1B%5B0m:6:%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20parsing%20alone%20solves%20most%20of%20the%20compiler%20related%20problems%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mCompilers/3goals/.todo%1B%5B0m:12:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mDjango/.todo%1B%5B0m:10:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20Pinar%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mDjango/Django-admin.py/.todo%1B%5B0m:9:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20install%20the%20tab%20completion%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mDjango/GettingStarted/Basics-manage.py-startapp/.todo%1B%5B0m:7:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20__init__.py%20is%20also%20created%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mDjango/GettingStarted/tempaltetags/.todo%1B%5B0m:11:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20tests%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Flags/.todo%1B%5B0m:5:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20combine%20statements%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:26:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20swaps%20the%20words%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:35:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20the%20use%20of%20%5C1,%20which%20takes%20the%201st%20match%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:41:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20add%20brackets%20around%20each%20matches%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Getting-started/.todo%1B%5B0m:51:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20remove%20duplicates%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mED-SED/SED/Matches/.todo%1B%5B0m:3:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20sed%20-ie%20%27s/SO/so%27%20app.yaml%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0A%1B%5B1;32mEmacs/.todo%1B%5B0m:21:%1B%5B30;43mNB%1B%5B0m%20same%20commands%20as%20in%20terminal%1B%5B0m%1B%5BK%0ABinary%20file%20Emacs/keybindings/emacs-keywords.png%20matches%0A%1B%5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox takes URLs on its command line; open takes files. ack's stdout is not a URL (or a file). Instead, you'll need to write ack's output to a file, and have firefox open that.

```
ack-grep -a NB > ~/ack-out.txt
open -a Firefox ~/ack-out.txt
```

I'm not sure why you *want* to do this, but that should work. Note that you probably won't get color this way; ack does not write HTML AFAIK.

Comment: @derobert: Can you choose the encoding somehow at the terminal? -- I get the output, for instance: [1;32mAWK/.todo[0m:5

Comment: Try the --nocolor option. That should be the default with a redirect, but who knows. (Those weird things you're seeing are the color codes)