# What does '**' mean in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, pointers, operators

What does it mean when an object has two asterisks at the beginning?

```cpp
**variable
```

Comment: @Andreas People jump all over the trivial questions, because they get lots of views (106 so far) and thus lots of upvotes. Hence [16 upvotes in 17 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893129/what-does-mean-in-c/2893145#2893145) for a relatively basic answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

Comment: @Andreas:  I'm surprised there were so many direct answers to such an... how should I say, _indirect_ question.  ;-)

Comment: In addition to being easy rep, simple questions aso have the widest audience. I could answer this question, you could answer this question, a person who's three weeks into his first CS class could probably answer this question, etc. So even if a lower percentage of people choose to answer, it's still likely to get a lot of answers. That's an unfortunate flaw in the SO system — rare knowledge is likely to receive less reward.

Comment: Without any code surprised no-one offered up multiplication using a pointer.  result = x **pointer;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \*\* in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644981/what-is-in-c)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is pointer to pointer.

For more details you can check: [Pointer to pointer](http://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx8.html)

It can be good, for example, for dynamically allocating multidimensional arrays:

Like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
if(array == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit or return
}

for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
    array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to demonstrate properly freeing the multidimensional array in reverse order of allocation.

Comment: Yes you are right :). Not forget to use 
 for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
  free(array[i]);
 free(array); 
to free allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you. That link was the most beneficial.

Answer (score 56):

In a declaration, it means it's a pointer to a pointer:

```
int **x;  // declare x as a pointer to a pointer to an int
```

When using it, it deferences it twice:

```
int x = 1;
int *y = &x;  // declare y as a pointer to x
int **z = &y;  // declare z as a pointer to y
**z = 2;  // sets the thing pointed to (the thing pointed to by z) to 2
          // i.e., sets x to 2
```

Comment: And what if you were to set z to 2 using just one point *z = 2 ??

Comment: @num It would change y to point to the memory location 2, and `*y = 1;` or `**z = 1;` would both try to change the memory at address 2, which is almost certainly outside the legal range you've been allocated

Answer (score 6):

It means that the variable is a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Pointer to a pointer when declaring the variable.

Double pointer de-reference when used outside the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use cdecl to explain C-types.

There's an online interface here: http://cdecl.org/. Enter "int **x" into the text field and check the result.

Answer (score 2):

**variable is double dereference. If variable is an address of an address, the resulting expression will be the lvalue at the address stored in *variable.

It can mean different things if it's a part of declaration:

type **variable would mean, on the other hand, a pointer to a pointer, that is, a variable that can hold address of another variable, which is also a pointer, but this time to a variable of type 'type'

Answer (score 2):

It means that the variable is dereferenced twice. Assume you have a pointer to a pointer to char like this:

char** variable = ...;

If you want to access the value this pointer is pointing to, you have to dereference it twice:

**variable

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to a pointer. You can use this if you want to point to an `array`, or a `const char *` (string). Also, in Objective-C with Cocoa this is often used to point to an `NSError*`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer to another pointer

Comment: If he's asking a question this basic, he probably needs the concept of a pointer explained, too.

Answer (score 1):

** is a pointer to a pointer. These are sometimes used for arrays of strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to pointer.

As in if *x means that it will contain an address of some variable then if i say

m=&x then m is shown as

int **m