# What scenarios would ** be useful?

Tags: c++, c, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

I saw a question about ** (pointer to a pointer) in C [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893129/what-does-mean-in-c). I'd like to know whats the point of this? When should I use it?

Comment: Related, maybe not quite a duplicate sort-ofishly:  [Uses for multiple levels of pointer dereferences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758673/uses-for-multiple-levels-of-pointer-dereferences)

Answer (score 7):

Whenever You need a pointer to a pointer :).

For example, if You want to dynamically allocate an array of pointers, operator new or malloc will return a pointer pointing to the first pointer in the array.

Other use might be, to pass a pointer to pointer, to a function, so the function can modify the original pointer. In C++, You can pass by reference, but not in C.

Comment: Then again, why would you ever want to allocate an array of anything with operator new?

Comment: @avakar: to allocate an array of char* for instance?

Comment: @nico: On StackOverflow I have received the advice to use a vector of chars rather than use `new`.

Comment: You need an x amount of pointers but you don't know how many you will need :P Then a pointer to a pointer is handy.

Comment: To check the newly acquired knowledge, when reading a textbook, and before getting smart enough, to know better, and use a vector. Ok maybe new is a bad idea, but there are still environments in the wild, where malloc is all You have

Comment: @dreamlax: well, although in 95% of the cases I'd use a `std::vector` for simple tasks I find using arrays easier. In any case if we're talking C there's no other option :)

Comment: Note that this question is about __both C and C++__. In C, if you need a dynamically sized  array of strings, a... um... _very popular way_ to do that is to have a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to the first elements of character arrays. Thus doing so you will have a pointer to pointers, a `char**`.

Answer (score 5):

When you have a function which wants to increment a pointer to a c-string. This is needed for things like recursive-descent parsers where each rule is responsible for incrementing things...

Comment: +1 Must not be a pointer to a string though, could be any data.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yes, it could be any data; but strings are the only thing I've ever needed it for.

Comment: Note that a pointer to a pointer is only necessary for this in C, in C++ you should pass a reference to a pointer for that. (And I really, really don't want to start any religious war over whether that makes more or less sense than the C way. I justed wanted to point out the fact.)

Answer (score 3):

In some variation of this:

```
void PutNewObjectHere(Class **dp) {
 *dp = new Class;
}

Class *p;
PutNewObjectHere(&p);
delete p;
```

(Note, this is a silly example for illustration.  It would normally return the new pointer.  The concept, however, does occasionally come up in practice)

Comment: It is often used when the function returns some error/success value, i.e. init functions. `Handler *handler; if (init(&handler)) {...}` with `int init(Handler **handler) { if (!check_stuff()) return 0; *handler = get_new_handler(); return 1; }`

Comment: @dbemerlin: Yes, exactly.  But I left out the clutter since it's orthogonal to pointer usage :)

Answer (score 2):

It's commonly used for out parameters that are pointers, e.g.:

```
bool GetSomeObject(SomeObject** object) { 
    *object = new SomeObject();
    // ... initialize object or whatever ...
}
```

And you would call it like thus:

```
SomeObject* object;
if (GetSomeObject(&object)) {
    // ... use object ...
    delete object;
}
```

This is a common pattern where the callee allocates and the caller frees...

Answer (score 2):

You want a C function to mutate a pointer passed as argument, and it's C so there's no pass-by-reference.  Therefore you pass a pointer to the pointer.  Here's a favorite example adapted from Dave Hanson's  [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/):

```
void Bit_free(struct Bit_T **set) {
    assert(set && *set);
    free(*set);
    *set = NULL;
}
```

By writing `NULL` into the freed pointer, you prevent it from dangling.

Answer (score 1):

This is called double indirection, meaning you have a pointer to another pointer, which in turn points to some useful data (or in rare cases yet another pointer).

There's a good article at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#Double_indirection) that covers pointers in general and has a good section on double indirection.

Answer (score 0):

In particular I've used these kind of pointers in the context of an array. For instance in my 8086 emulator project I had an array of function pointers. So it ended up looking like this:

```
instruction_functions[(int)opcode]();
```

This is also known as a jump table(sorta) and is used in a lot of places for optimization purposes.