# What does ** mean in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, variables, memory-management

I am reading a c++ code and came across this line:

```
    mem_cMemRow ** ppMemory = (mem_cMemRow **)malloc(//size of some structs);
```

It seems to me that ** reserves some amount or portions of the memory but my search did not yield any good results. I appreciate any deeper and more detailed explanations on this.

Comment: it's a pointer to a pointer

Comment: It is a pointer to a pointer. Read up on double pointers. A starter here: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html

Comment: I am sure this blog will help you to understand , what is pointer to pointer with example http://bytebeats.com/2011/08/08/pointer-to-pointer/

Comment: duplicate: [What is ** in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/644981/995714), [what does ** mean in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2893129/995714), [What is double star](http://stackoverflow.com/q/604099/995714). And [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 mem_cMemRow ** ppMemory = (mem_cMemRow **)malloc(//size of some structs)
```

is trying to allocate memory for `ppMemry`, which is a pointer to pointer type of `mem_cMemRow` objects. It (ppMemory) is a 2D dynamic array.

Answer (score 2):

Its a pointer to a pointer.  Essentially you are creating an array of pointers to a given struct.  Most likely the malloc is the sizeof a struct pointer times by some number.

Answer (score 1):

One star means a pointer. Two stars mean a pointer to a pointer. So, `ppMemory` is a pointer to a pointer to a `mem_cMemRow`.