# Can arrays in C be stored in non-sequential pointers?

Tags: c, arrays

This is a conceptual question for me to understand C better. From what I understand about C arrays, they store pointers to values which are generated in sequence as per the space allocated. So for example, if I have this code

```
char someCharArray[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Let's say my heap doesn't have sequential 12 bits for this array, so I store pointers to the following non-sequential addresses `0x001, 0x011, 0x040`.

I know two ways of accessing values from this array as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645111/4871483).

Let's say I access the second element of the array like this

```
char datPointer = someCharArray[1];
```

In this case, `datPointer` will point to `0x011` because the address is stored in the array.

However, wouldn't the following code return the wrong address?

```
char datWrongPointer = (someCharArray + 1);
```

Because I'm adding sequential addresses to the starting address of someCharArray, so assuming chars are 4 bits I'll get `datWrongPointer` to be `0x004` instead of what it should be? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the addition function but I'd appreciate if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: "*From what I understand about C arrays, they store pointers to values*" <- no, they just store values :o and the code following looks **very** wrong :o

Comment: *From what I understand about C arrays, they store pointers to values which are generated in sequence as per the space allocated* - hm. No. Arrays is just a **contiguous** memory region where values are stored sequentially.

Comment: Lol. Can you add an answer that explains it better? I've been reading a few Unix and C books and it's just not clicking. There was a point today when I thought the dereference `*` was overloaded and sometimes return pointers and sometimes didn't, so I'm lost.

Comment: I would add an answer if I fully understood what you are trying to do ....

Comment: Forget about pointers for a moment. They are irrelevant for (this) array discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understand about C arrays, they store pointers to values

No, arrays store values directly. In fact, arrays essentially *are* their elements. C adds no additional structure.

> ```
> char someCharArray[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
> ```

OK, here `someCharArray` consists of 3 bytes of memory. If it lives in static storage (e.g. because it's a global variable), this memory is typically part of the data section; if it lives in automatic memory (i.e. it's a local variable), it's typically placed on the stack.

> Let's say my heap doesn't have sequential 12 bits for this array

How is the heap involved here? Why 12 bits? C doesn't really support objects smaller than 1 byte (and bytes cannot be smaller than 8 bits).

Let's say for the sake of an example that `someCharArray` ends up being placed at address 0xAB0000. Then the first element lives at 0xAB0000, the second element at 0xAB0001, and the third element at 0xAB0002.

> ```
> char datPointer = someCharArray[1];
> ```

`datPointer` is not a pointer, it's a single `char`. This code will assign `'b'` to `datPointer` (because `someCharArray[1]` is `'b'`).

> ```
> char datWrongPointer = (someCharArray + 1);
> ```

This is a type error.

`someCharArray` evaluates to a pointer to its first element (as arrays do unless they're the operand of `sizeof` or `&`). This gives us a value of type `char *` (and per above, the value is 0xAB0000).

We add 1, which adds enough bytes to get to the next element in memory. Here the pointer type is `char *`, so we're adding `1 * sizeof (char)` (which is just `1 * 1`, which is just `1`) to the raw pointer value.

We end up with a `char *` whose value is 0xAB0001.

We then try to assign a pointer to a plain `char`, which is not valid. But we could dereference the pointer with `*` and fetch the value stored there:

```
char x = *(someCharArray + 1);  // 'b'
```

... or we could use a pointer variable:

```
char *ptr = someCharArray + 1;  // 0xAB0001 in this example
```

Comment: Changed my question to reflect a proper initialization. If arrays store values and not pointers as I understood, do they have to allocate all their memory at once (don't know where this would be, I thought this was allocated but heap but maybe I'm wrong), so essentially arrays are pointers to a large chunk of memory that contains smaller subsets of data?

Comment: @ytpillai Arrays are allocated all at once, like all other types. Arrays are not pointers. Arrays are a collection of elements placed contiguously in memory, plus some weird conversion rules (almost all uses of an array in C code end up implicitly converting the array to a pointer to its first element ("pointer decay")).

Comment: @ytpillai ... PS: If you see any tutorial talking about "the name of an array", throw it away. Names don't matter.

Comment: Your answer is the best I've ever seen. Thanks so much for the work you out into it, I can finally get past that whole confusion. I've accepted but I think if you put it somewhere more accessible than this question as well you can really help a lot of people.